# How to validate and store Drupal commerce Checkout Date and Time

Tags: rules, commerce

I am working on catering services Drupal Commerce website in which each catering companies having open hours(for eg: 8 AM to 11 30 PM) with Open, Busy and Closed statuses.  The objective is that, when a user select a date , time of event and purchases(add to cart and check out) a food item it should check the entered time is valid between open hours of the caterer whose status is Open. The selected time and date should keep and show in all checkout out operations and orders.

Is it possible with rules or commerce conditions or any other modules

Please help